# Using Multiple where condition and variables in laravel 5 MYSQL Query

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

This my query in which I want to use variables to be compared with the fields in the database table to get the price field from it.

```
 $price = DB::table('price')
       ->where([
    ['days_id', '=',  $days] , ['deals_id' , '=', $selected_deal]
        ])
       ->value('price');
```

Comment: try out :- `DB::table("price")->select("price")->where([["day_id","=",$days], ["deals_id","=",$selected_deal]])->get();`

Comment: It's is not working the result is 

Illuminate\Support\Collection Object ( [items:protected] => Array ( ) )

Comment: separate your where clause `where("day_id","=",$days)->where("deals_id","=",$selected_deal)`

Comment: still passing empty array

Comment: `$days and $selected_deal` both are an array ??

Comment: No I'm getting these values from session:---    $selected_deal = session('selected_deal');
       $days = session('days');  

       $price = DB::table('price')->select('price')
       ->where("days_id","=", $days)
       ->where("deals_id","=", $selected_deal)
        ->get();

Comment: why you use php sesion when laravel provide its own?

Comment: Laravel Session was not working so..